# How do I draw a triangle using a solid color without interpolation in the fragment shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

This should really be a simple task, but I fail miserably. First a confession: I know very little about OpenGL and the few things I've learned come from various tutorials (some of which are probably outdated and deprecated)

I'm trying to draw a quad using a single color defined at runtime. The quad is drawn in the correct size and position but with the wrong color. This is my vertex and fragment shader:

```
public static final String VS_SOLIDCOLOR =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;" +
        "attribute vec4 aColor;" +
        "varying vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;" +
        "  vColor = aColor;" +
        "}";

public static final String FS_SOLIDCOLOR =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "varying vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";
```

The color is set like this (I have removed gl error check and check for colorHandle == -1):

```
    float r = 1.0f;
    float g = 0.0f;
    float b = 0.0f;
    float a = 1.0f;
    final int colorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgramSolidColor, "aColor");
    GLES20.glVertexAttrib4f(colorHandle, r, g, b, a);
```

I would have expected the above code to result in solid red triangles, but they end up as solid yellow. From what I've read the fragment shader will interpolate the vColor vector, but I don't want that (and I'm not sure why it ends up as yellow). How do I set a color at runtime and get that drawn unchanged on my triangles?

PS If I were to do this in the fragment shader I would get a solid red color for my entire quad:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
```

Let me know if you need me to post more code.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I did wrong. I was under the impression that I could only set variables in the vertex shader at runtime, but it's possible to manipulate the fragment shader as well. My shader should look like this:

```
public static final String VS_SOLIDCOLOR =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 aPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;" +
        "}";

public static final String FS_SOLIDCOLOR =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform vec4 uColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = uColor;" +
        "}";
```

And set like this:

```
    final int colorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramSolidColor, "uColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4f(colorHandle, r, g, b, a);
```